# VBA with Wonderware Historian tags

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel function that loads Wonderware tags and it works great but i want to have the user click in a button and loads those tags automatically no matter what cell they are on in the excel sheet.How can that be done. The formula function i'm using is

```
=wwWideHistory3("LEWC2012INSQL", Sheet1!$A$17:$A$21,"Row7",AFStartBinding,AFEndBinding,254,0,0,0,0,3,0,"",3,"",-1,0,"","NoFilter",20480)
```

then after the function is loaded i want to refresh the sheet.

Comment: @Jeannie it's unclear what you are actually asking here.  Eg, Do you want help with VBA to write that formula into the active cell?

Comment: Record a macro and edit the code ;)

Comment: yes i need help with the vba to write the formulla into a the next cell